# NullPointerException while trying to read int from file with Scanner

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read information from a file. The first thing in the file is an integer, but when I try to read it I get a NullPointerException. I also tried reading the first thing in the file as a string, and again I got a NullPointerException. I then added the print statement that is in the catch statement when I connect the file. When I run the code, that print statement is evaluated. What is the source of my issue? Thanks.

```
private boolean collectSystem(String loc) {
    Scanner fileIn = null;
    try {
        fileIn = new Scanner(new File(loc));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found, IntakeSystem");
    }

    // Determine number of equations
    try {
        n = fileIn.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        return false;
    }

    // Collect the text in the file as a string
    String info = "";
    while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
        info = info + fileIn.nextLine();
    }

    fileIn.close();

    //Separate equations in file
    String[] eqns = new String[n];
    int start = 0;
    int end = info.indexOf(";");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(end == -1) return false;
        String nextLine = info.substring(start, end);
        eqns[i] = nextLine;
        start = end + 1;
        end = info.indexOf(";", start);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println(eqns[n]);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you mark in the code, where exactly you are getting NPE?

Comment: I suspect that your code is throwing a `FileNotFoundException`, but because you just swallow the exception (and print it out), the code moves on to the `fileIn.nextInt()` and throws a NPE on `fileIn`.

Comment: use `e.printStackTrace()` while development in catch block.

Comment: File not found, IntakeSystem
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at IntakeSystem.collectSystem(IntakeSystem.java:37)
 at IntakeSystem.<init>(IntakeSystem.java:21)
 at IntakeSystem.main(IntakeSystem.java:70)

Comment: Now you got the reason. `fileIn` object is null.

Comment: When I remove the print statement and print the stack trace from  that catch block this is what I get

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/dimitrileggas/Documents/Research Projects/Crystal Structure/Unique Structure Results/testdoc (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636)
 at IntakeSystem.collectSystem(IntakeSystem.java:30)
 at IntakeSystem.<init>(IntakeSystem.java:21)
 at IntakeSystem.main(IntakeSystem.java:70)

Comment: and then:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at IntakeSystem.collectSystem(IntakeSystem.java:37)
 at IntakeSystem.<init>(IntakeSystem.java:21)
 at IntakeSystem.main(IntakeSystem.java:70)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments what is happening is that you are passing in a path that points to a file that doesn't exist, Make sure you are actually passing in a valid file path first.

A way to make it easier with debugging:

Replace `System.out.println("File not found, IntakeSystem");` in the first catch block with `throw new IllegalArguementException(e)` or `return false;`, because otherwise your file object will still be null and the execution will continue if the `String loc` argument does not point to an existing file; Which via the OP comments is your issue.

Comment: Thanks, this sent me down the right path. For some reason it was unable to recognize rich text files. I had to convert to plain text file and then there was no issue. Thanks again